# Returning parent of a child in an xml document using python and lxml/xpath

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Given a child node in an xml file, how do you return reference to its immediate parent in python, say using lxml/xpath?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is getparrent() not working?

Comment: After locating each leaf node, the xpath 'ancestor::*' would return all ancestors of the leaf. And if only ancestors with a certain tag name are needed (e.g. with tag name of "tagName"), then 'ancestor::tagname' works.